# php if-elseif function with condition (issue)

Tags: php

I wrote a php function containing an if-statement, but it does not seem to work. (I have experienced this already once and I'm wondering why)

This is the function:

```
function calculate_price_index($price){
    if($price > 0 && $price <= 99){
        $price_index = 8;   
    } elseif($price >= 100 && $price <= 199){
        $price_index = 1;   
    } elseif($price >= 200 && $price <= 299){
        $price_index = 2;   
    } elseif($price >= 300 && $price <= 399){
        $price_index = 3;   
    } elseif($price >= 400 && $price <= 499){
        $price_index = 4;   
    } elseif($price >= 500 && $price <= 599){
        $price_index = 5;   
    } elseif($price >= 600 && $price <= 699){
        $price_index = 6;   
    } elseif($price >= 700){
        $price_index = 7;   
    }
}
```

And I would like to execute it like this:

```
calculate_price_index($_POST['price']);
echo $price_index;
```

But it does not echo anything. When I do not declare this as a function, however, it works fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You must use , in end of function

```
return $price_index;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do that (not wondering about your if-else that can be very lighter) :

1. Function must return price_index so end it with *return $price_index;*

and write

```
echo calculate_price_index($_POST['price']);
```

2. use Global in your function and start it by *global $price_index;*

Answer (score 1):

```
function calculate_price_index($price){
    if($price > 0 && $price <= 99){
        $price_index = 8;   
    } elseif($price >= 100 && $price <= 199){
        $price_index = 1;   
    } elseif($price >= 200 && $price <= 299){
        $price_index = 2;   
    } elseif($price >= 300 && $price <= 399){
        $price_index = 3;   
    } elseif($price >= 400 && $price <= 499){
        $price_index = 4;   
    } elseif($price >= 500 && $price <= 599){
        $price_index = 5;   
    } elseif($price >= 600 && $price <= 699){
        $price_index = 6;   
    } elseif($price >= 700){
        $price_index = 7;   
    }
 // return your values from here
 return $price_index;
}
```

And I would like to execute it like this:

```
$price_index = calculate_price_index($_POST['price']);
echo $price_index;
```

Answer (score 1):

you might be using global `$price_index`

In PHP, global variables need to be used like so:

```
function calculate_price_index($price){
    if($price > 0 && $price <= 99){
         $GLOBALS['price_index'] = 8;   
    } elseif($price >= 100 && $price <= 199){
         $GLOBALS['price_index'] = 1;   
    } elseif($price >= 200 && $price <= 299){
         $GLOBALS['price_index'] = 2;   
    } elseif($price >= 300 && $price <= 399){
         $GLOBALS['price_index'] = 3;   
    } elseif($price >= 400 && $price <= 499){
         $GLOBALS['price_index'] = 4;   
    } elseif($price >= 500 && $price <= 599){
         $GLOBALS['price_index'] = 5;   
    } elseif($price >= 600 && $price <= 699){
         $GLOBALS['price_index'] = 6;   
    } elseif($price >= 700){
         $GLOBALS['price_index'] = 7;   
    }
}
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the echo() function inside the calculate_price_index() function. I edited your code:

```
<?php
function calculate_price_index($price){
if($price > 0 && $price <= 99){
    $price_index = 8;   
} elseif($price >= 100 && $price <= 199){
    $price_index = 1;   
} elseif($price >= 200 && $price <= 299){
    $price_index = 2;   
} elseif($price >= 300 && $price <= 399){
    $price_index = 3;   
} elseif($price >= 400 && $price <= 499){
    $price_index = 4;   
} elseif($price >= 500 && $price <= 599){
    $price_index = 5;   
} elseif($price >= 600 && $price <= 699){
    $price_index = 6;   
} elseif($price >= 700){
    $price_index = 7;   
}
echo $price_index;
}
calculate_price_index(500);
?>
```

If you are going to use $_POST, make sure to convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the variable to use at the end like:

```
 return $price_index;
```